# Go bufio.Scanner stops while reading TCP connection to Redis

Tags: tcp, go, redis

Reading TCP connection between Redis-server by using `bufio.Scanner`

```
fmt.Fprintf(conn, "*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$5\r\nmykey\r\n$7\r\nHello!!\r\n")
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
for {
    // fmt.Println("marker00")
    if ok := scanner.Scan(); !ok {
        // fmt.Println("marker01")
        break
    }
    // fmt.Println("marker02")
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

"+OK" comes as the result for first scanning, but the second scanning stops just in invoking `Scan` method. (marker00 -> marker02 -> marker00 and no output any more)

Why does `Scan` stop and how can I know the end of TCP response (without using `bufio.Reader`)?

Comment: It does work for a simple String (http://play.golang.org/p/Z3oMRi5A0g), so it should indicate here that the output of the first `Scan()` somehow got the full content of `conn`. Did you try `scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bufio.NewReader(conn))`?

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the comment! Yes, I tried NewScanner of NewReader. And the full contents of conn response will be only "+OK" in this case. (@see https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BvyUw1ECQAE3vaQ.jpg )

Comment: What is the first output of the only `scanner.Text()` that you manage to get?

Comment: It is "+OK", enough response I want, but the problem is that it never ends. (I made a gist to reproduce this problem https://gist.github.com/otiai10/3cf030e2f7816a59347f check if you don't mind)

Comment: What do you expect? Redis does not close the connection for you after sending a command. Scan() ends after io.EOF which is not sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis does not close the connection for you after sending a command. Scan() ends after io.EOF which is not sent.

Check out this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

// before go run, you must hit `redis-server` to wake redis up
func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
    message := "*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$1\r\na\r\n$1\r\nb\r\n"

    go func(conn net.Conn) {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Fprintf(conn, message)
        }
    }(conn)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for {
        if ok := scanner.Scan(); !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    fmt.Println("Scanning ended")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can understand why `Scan` stopped and realized I have to implement some functions to judge the end of message-response (if using `bufio.Scanner`).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue. Two solutions:

1) Add a "QUIT\r\n" command to your Redis message. This will cause Redis to close the connection which will terminate the scan. You'll have to deal with the extra "+OK" that the quit outputs.

2) Add

`conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second*5))`

just before you start scanning. This will cause the scan to stop trying after 5 seconds. Unfortunately, it will always take 5 seconds to complete the scan so choose this time wisely.